# how I should display the multiple item in the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display some multiple valus in dropdown with autocomplete

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Client-ville_id').typeahead({
        source: function (query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "list_ville.php",
                data: 'query=' + query,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    result($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            name: item.name,
                            cp:item.departement_code
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ville WHERE name LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$search_param);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $countryResult[] = $row["name"];
        $countryResult[] = $row["departement_code"];
    }
    echo json_encode($countryResult);
}
$conn->close();
```

But I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null at (index):531

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating array with strings in php, you need

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $countryResult[] = array(
          "name" => $row["name"],
          "departement_code" => $row["departement_code"]
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($countryResult);
}
```

or just:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $countryResult[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($countryResult);
}
```

there is function that fetch all data in one function call, here is one for mysqli: [mysqli_result::fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

Comment: yes, it work but it 'not display the two items on the same input
by example, 
 result($.map(data, function (item) {
                            name: item.name;
                            cp:item.departement_code;
                            return name + '-' + cp;
                        }));

Comment: founded
`result($.map(data, function (item) {
     return item.name + '-' + item.departement_code;
  }));`
but another pb/
It display "paris-undefined"

Answer (score -1):

In your sql file do

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ville WHERE name LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$search_param);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$i = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $countryResult[$i]['name'] = $row["name"];
        $countryResult[$i]['departement_code'] = $row["departement_code"];
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($countryResult);
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: In that solution he will only get the last element because the `$countryResult['name']` will be overwritten every time.

Comment: Yes, i update my code to prevent overwrite record. @Krzysztof Janiszewski

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you create a non associative array, but reffer to it as associative.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $countryResult[] = $row["name"];
    $countryResult[] = $row["departement_code"];
}
```

After this loop `$countryResult` array would like something like this

```
array(6) {
  [0] => "name1"
  [1] => "departement_code1"
  [2] => "name2"
  [3] => "departement_code2"
  [4] => "name3"
  [5] => "departement_code3"
}
```

You should change the `while` loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $countryResult[] = $row;
}
```